# Suspend problem ubuntu 18.04 Dell latitude 5480

Tags: 18.04, dell

I have a Dell latitude 5480. When I used Ubuntu 16.04 and it worked fine without any issue, suspend/resume worked like a charm in Ubuntu 16.04. But after installing Ubuntu 18.04 I cannot suspend the system while the charger is unplugged.

When the charger cable is plugged in when I close and open the lid, the suspend resume works, but in battery mode (without plugging in the charger) when I close and open the lid, no resume.

I have to press to power button and whole system start from the beginning; resume is not working. I have tried a lot of things recommended over the internet even by downgrading the kernel to 4.13 (currently i have 4.15.0-23-generic), but downgrading the kernel didn't solved the issue.

I've installed gnome tweak tool and enabled suspend in lid close. My graphic card is Intel HD 620. I have installed Ubuntu in legacy mode not in UEFI mode. My problem is suspend resume worked fine with Ubuntu 16.04, but why not in 18.04 and why suspend resume only works in 18.04 when the power cable is plugged?

Comment: Was you able to solve that?

Comment: Yes, I installed ubuntu 18.04 using UEFI mode instead of Legacy then it worked